# kivy - bind popup dismiss to function from another widget instance

Tags: popup, kivy

I would like to bind the dismiss of a popup (or the press of a button in that popup widget) to a function from the widget that opens this popup.

More specificly,

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MainBox>:

    SelectButton:
        id: selectbutton
        text: 'Select'
        on_press: Factory.SelectPopup().open()

    Button:
       text: 'Ask'
       background_color: (0,1,0,1) if selectbutton.selected else (1,0,0,1)

<SelectPopup>:
    title: 'Select from List'
    auto_dismiss: False
    on_dismiss: Factory.SelectButton().set_selection()
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'hello'
        Button:
            text: 'ok'
            #on_press: Factory.SelectButton().set_selection()
            on_press: root.dismiss()
```

and in the .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class SelectButton(Button):
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)

    def set_selection(self):
        self.selected = True

class SelectPopup(Popup):
    pass        

class MainBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SelectButtonApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SelectButtonApp().run()
```

That is, I would like to set the attribute `selected` from the `SelectButton` to `True` when I dismiss the popup that is opened by pressing the `SelectButton`. The way tried doesn't work, I guess because the `on_dismiss` call does not refer to the `SelectButton` instance in the `MainBox`. I also tried working with `ids` but appearently one cannot pass them around easily between unrelated widgets like the `MainBox` and the `SelectPopup`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `app.root.ids` to access item. There are two solutions.

## Solution 1 - direct access i.e. don't call set_selection() function

Directly referencing `selected` i.e. *without* `set_selection()` function.

```
Button:
    text: 'ok'
    on_press:
        app.root.ids.selectbutton.selected = True
        root.dismiss()
```

## Solution 2 - call set_selection() function

Invoke set_selection() function.

```
Button:
    text: 'ok'
    on_press:
        app.root.ids.selectbutton.set_selection()
        root.dismiss()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - selected changed to True after popup dismissed]